Trying to Intercept a setter on a field using AOP springboot
I am trying to modify a field value while setting it. I am trying to use spring AOP. Here is my code so far
// Translate class

    import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
    import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
    import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
    import java.lang.annotation.Target;
    
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target(ElementType.FIELD)
    public @interface Translate {
    }


//Aspect class

@Aspect
@Component
public class TranslationAspect {

    @Autowired
    private TranslationService translationService;

    @Pointcut("@annotation(com.proj.si.api.annotations.Translate)")
    public void translateField() {
    }

    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "translateField()", returning = "target")
    public void translate(Object target) throws IllegalAccessException {
        Field[] fields = target.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            if (field.isAnnotationPresent(Translate.class)) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                Object value = field.get(target);
                if (value instanceof String) {
                    String translatedValue = translationService.getTranslation((String) value);
                    field.set(target, translatedValue);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//Config class
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class AspectConfig {
}

// POJO
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ResponseObt implements Serializable {
    @Translate
    private String name;

I think this code intercepts while calling the getter of the field (which does not work). However, I want to modify this code for a setter

Firstly, AOP can only be applied to methods.
Secondly, when modifying the return value, one can only change the attributes of the original object, not the object's reference(thus, if the return value of a method is a String, then it cannot be modified). Here's an example:

Correct

@AfterReturning(value = "pointCut()", returning = "obj")
public Object doAfterReturning(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object obj) {
    User user = (User)obj;
    user.setName("test");
    return user;
}


Incorrect

@AfterReturning(value = "pointCut()", returning = "obj")
public Object doAfterReturning(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object obj) {
    User user = new User();
    obj = user;
    return obj;
}


Please, be polite enough to either accept and upvote my answer or comment on it, if anything is unclear or wrong about it. Thank you.

@annotation() pointcuts target annotated methods' executions, i.e. you are using the wrong pointcut designator. What you need is set(), but that one is not available in Spring AOP. You need to switch to native AspectJ, which is most easily achieved by -javaagent:/path/to/aspectjweaver.jar.
Resources:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/aop/using-aspectj.html
https://eclipse.dev/aspectj/doc/latest/progguide/progguide.html#quick, search for set(Signature)
https://eclipse.dev/aspectj/doc/latest/progguide/progguide.html#semantics-pointcuts, search for set(FieldPattern)
https://eclipse.dev/aspectj/doc/latest/progguide/progguide.html#_field_related_pointcuts
https://eclipse.dev/aspectj/doc/latest/adk15notebook/adk15notebook.html#_example_pointcuts, search for set(@Cachable * *)

If for whatever reason you wish to avoid using AspectJ, refactor your code to make sure that all field write access goes throught a setter method and annotate that method instead. Then, you can use @annotation().
